# How to avoid flickering with uncleared framebuffers (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

When I don't clear the default framebuffer, or just draw only a portion of it, I can see some flickering from previously drawn frames.

I can see that this is something connected to the iOS EAGLLayer renderbuffer policy, but I don't understand whats happenig, so I can't step forward to solve the problem.

I have turned on retained backing, but it seems that there are wrong regions redrawn (like regions from older threads?), so flickering still exists.

How to overcome this flickering? Anybody had experience here?

Or at least can you just explain the iOS renderbuffer presenting policy?

Comment: Partial redraw has a huge impact on performance, I have no intention to omit this feature.

Comment: Do you use glClear() the very first time you draw to this framebuffer? If no, you're going to have uninitialized data in there. You don't need to clear on subsequent frames, but it might help to start the first one fresh.

Answer (score 0):

the time delay in between previously drawn frames. and current frames are not proper timing.